# DatabaseFacade does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlCommand'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I wish to run a raw SQL Delete Query on EF Core and I am suing the following guide to help me along:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

The code:

```
using (accountingContext db = new())
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM ...");
}
```

but I get the error:

**DatabaseFacade does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlCommand'**

my accountingContext class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public partial class accountingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction>? Transactions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TransactionStaging>? TransactionsStaging { get; set; }

        public accountingContext()
        {
        }

        public accountingContext(DbContextOptions<accountingContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("****");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="28.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.9">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.6">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.15.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Resources\Temp\" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: EF6 != EF Core.

Comment: Try use `ExecuteSqlRaw`.  But there's also a `.Remove(entity)` that will do the trick.

Comment: @PaulSinnema same issue with ExecuteSqlRaw.  Cannot use Remove unfortunately, I must send a raw DELETE statement.  Can't understand why this won't compile

Comment: @MusaffarPatel that's weird. Are you shure you use EF 6.0?

Comment: @PaulSinnema using EF Core 6, below is my dependency from .csprjo file:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.6">

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following resolved the issue for me:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("...");
```

Not sure why all the docs I was going through were suggesting the use of ExecuteSqlCommand but eventually I stumbled on the correct command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following packages to be able to use the EF 6.0:

[image]

Don't use any other EntityFramework packages. Also, your solution should be for .Net 6.0.

Comment: I am using .Net 6.0 and I have installed the packages you suggested:  I've modified my question to show my .csproj file .. the problem persists however

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't you find the `ExecuteSqlRaw`. And why can't you use the `.Remove()`?

Comment: It turns out I missed your comment about using ExecuteSqlRaw, I blame it on being late night and the fact that my mind has been going around too long on this issue.   I have accepted your answer as you did provide it and it was my fault for missing it

Comment: I know the feeling ;-) But it's not the answer. Just uncheck it please. Others may think it is otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For EF Cor you need to use the *ExecuteSqlRaw* or *ExecuteSql* commands included in the Extensions Nuget package [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide more information than the existing answers (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73750310/10352740)), I think you should read the [help center for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), especially [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Reasons leading to answer deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).